# Video playback on cube Webgl / Three.js IOS

Tags: ios, three.js, html5-video, webvr

is it possible to get video playback working on a square with IOS?

Ideally the video would come from a youtube stream.

I have been searching but I cant find anything that seems to work.

My end goal is to make a WebVR web app that can play videos in IOS.

Thanks for any thoughts / advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my video or videosphere not playing on mobile in A-Frame VR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380912/why-is-my-video-or-videosphere-not-playing-on-mobile-in-a-frame-vr)

Comment: thanks for the link - I did find this which plays inline video in IOS http://bfred-it.github.io/iphone-inline-video/demo/ are there any limitations or things to consider, video formats and such?

Comment: Generally speaking, mp4 and webm work everywhere.

Comment: if anyones interested - got it working with https://aframe.io/ and then turned the page into an app with phonegap, hers another thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260216/a-frame-ios-inline-video-phonegap