# A-Frame IOS Inline video Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, aframe, webvr

Does anyone know if its possible to play inline video via A Frame in a Phonegap app?

I can get inline video working on my IPhone if the webpage is pinned to the home screen and I access the web page that way.

(How people are using it here: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/316)

When I try and run the page via phone gap, the video opens up in full screen.

I have pinned the server address to my homepage.

I don't know much about phone gap (its the first time i have used it) but have added :

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

to the config.xml

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you need to build the phonegap app. I added the preference:

```
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
```

I cant seem to get it working with the emulator but on my iPhone 5 it works fine.

:)