# 360 Vid working on laptop but not mobile

Tags: google-cardboard, aframe, 360-virtual-reality

Hoping someone might have some wisdom: I've been doing some tests running a 360 video in a-frame (hosting on github pages currently - https://ganttmd87.github.io/ )

I've had success loading on my computers browser, but get an empty black page (w/cardboard button in lower left) when loaded on mobile. I've tried using a 360 vid both with and w/out metadata, but no luck thus far.

Would be very grateful if anyone could offer some insight or advice - thanks a ton!
mg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my video or videosphere not playing on mobile in A-Frame VR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380912/why-is-my-video-or-videosphere-not-playing-on-mobile-in-a-frame-vr)

Comment: ah, yes. so I guess my answer won't help.

Comment: @ngokevin I think yr right - I found that one after the fact - same issue, but still havent been able to resolve it (read thru github issue #316 as well, which seemed like a definitive thread). I wonder if there have been any developments since? I noticed that on the aframe site, the videosphere examples are taken down on the mobile version

Answer (score 0):

I had a black screen on my desktop, too, when I clicked your link.

From my experiments with even small 360 degree video files I am pretty sure that it silently fails on first attempts to load because it runs into timeouts.
After some time, the file is in the cache and gets loaded and this is more likely to happen on a desktop than on mobile.

The standard timeout for a-asset is 3 seconds, according to the docs.
You might want to increase it like so:

```
<a-assets timeout="10000">
```

(via https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/core/asset-management-system.html#setting-a-timeout)

Comment: thanks for the response! I'll give that a go - I've been doing a fair amount of reading (this thread seems comprehensive) but all of the fixes listed (add meta tags, enable inline playing, pin to home page) dont seem to do much. Will keep digging and try the timeout fix.