# A-Frame: How do I add a button INSIDE of the a-scene tags that plays video on mobile?

Tags: javascript, video, mobile, aframe

I've created an A-Frame project that has a video inside of the scene. The video works as intended while in both desktop and mobile. The issue I'm having is that only the desktop version will allow me to have a button within the a-scene tags that plays the video, whereas the mobile version only allows me to use a button if it's OUTSIDE of the a-scene tags, like in a div wrapper. The logic to load and play the video and work the button works on both desktop and mobile, the only difference is when I target the logic to a button inside of the a-scene tags. As grateful as I am that the video is playing on mobile, I would really like to have a "VR" like button inside of the scene. As of now, the button that works on mobile acts more like a VR toggle button that initiates the scene and starts the video. That's not really the desired behavior I'm going for. FYI, I'm using the same type of a-image buttons throughout the scene to toggle actual images and static content and they work very well. It just seems to be having issues with video playback. This question is a follow up to another issue I had (resolved), found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48669965/videosphere-not-playing-video-in-a-frame-even-after-following-other-guidance/48670859?noredirect=1#comment84342699_48670859).

This works on desktop, but not mobile:

```
<body>

 <a-scene>

  <a-assets>
   <img id="buttonImg" src="button.png">
   <video id="video" src="video.mp4" webkit-playsinline></video>
  </a-assets>

  <a-image id="playButton" src="#buttonImg"></a-image>

  <a-videosphere id="videoShere" loop="true" src="#video"></a-videoshpere>

 </a-scene>

</body>
```

This works on both desktop and mobile:

```
<body>

 <div id="canvas">
  <div id="startButton">Play</div>
 </div>

 <a-scene>

  <a-assets>
   <img id="buttonImg" src="button.png">
   <video id="video" src="video.mp4" webkit-playsinline></video>
  </a-assets>

  <!--<a-image id="playButton" src="#buttonImg"></a-image>-->

  <a-videosphere id="videoShere" loop="true" src="#video"></a-videoshpere>

 </a-scene>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll still need the splash screen to init the video on mobile, then once it's triggered (activated via user gesture) you can apply an a-frame event to play it. The reason is that WebGL events are not considered user actions and are treated like JS triggered events instead.

Dom's description from this issue:

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1463#issuecomment-308138947

> The problem is that interaction within an A-Frame scene doesn't count. The browser can't tell what's going on inside WebGL, so it has to assume those events are just generated by arbitrary JS. You need an old-fashioned physical touchstart or click event, triggered by the user's finger (or Cardboard button) and not by a fuse or gaze cursor. Gamepad buttons might also count. I don't know of a live example of this though.

Here's the modified example from the last one that might be of help:
When the start button in the splash screen is clicked, it will play, then pause the video right away to satisfy the user gesture requirement.

Then I added a click handler to the play button (inside the VR scene) that should allow you to play the video. Like before, your milage may vary with the different browsers.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-video-click-play-inside-scene

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var scene = document.querySelector("a-scene");
    var vid = document.getElementById("video");
    var videoShere = document.getElementById("videoShere");
    var playButton = document.getElementById("playButton");

    if (scene.hasLoaded) {
      run();
    } else {
      scene.addEventListener("loaded", run);
    }

    playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      playVideo();
    });

    function run () {
      if(AFRAME.utils.device.isMobile()) {
        document.querySelector('#splash').style.display = 'flex';
        document.querySelector('#splash').addEventListener('click', function () {
          initVideo();
          this.style.display = 'none';
        })
      } else {
          initVideo();
      }
    }

    function initVideo () {
      vid.play();
      vid.pause();
      videoShere.components.material.material.map.image.play();
      videoShere.components.material.material.map.image.pause();
    }

    function playVideo () {
      vid.play();
      videoShere.components.material.material.map.image.play();
    }
   })
```

Comment: You're all over it man. Thanks again. I'll try it out and let you know how it goes. I guess that makes sense. I would have never guessed that there's so many hoops to jump through to get it to work. It seems like there just has to be deliberate loading of the scene in its entirety to get other features to work on mobile. I'll keep this in mind when dealing with other features!

Comment: Worked like a charm on both Android and iOS! Man, I've been battling this issue for days! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-gui

Use this npm. This is for creating button in a scene using a-frame. You can add button using this npm.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know there was an npm option for this. I'll keep this mind because I use buttons throughout every project I use. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Yes that's interesting and I used that.